# How can I use the Envato Market API to export a list of WordPress plugins?

Tags: wordpress, api

I'd like to use the [Envato API](https://build.envato.com/) to download a list of plugins for WordPress available on [Code Canyon](http://www.codecanyon.net/). However I have been unable to find a way to do so.

For example, I tried to use a get /search/item per their [documentation](https://build.envato.com/api/#search_GET_search_item_json) using the parameter category and setting it to "wordpress" however this returned a number of results but nowhere near the 6,040 the site says it has.

The document also mentions the "category code" is what I should be entering as the parameter for "category" but it never defines the category code - unfortunately, this seems common throughout the documentation - there isn't any definition. Another example of this is calling get /catalog/collection. The parameter required is "id" which it describes as "The numeric ID of the collection to return" - but what numeric ID? This one wasn't hard to figure out, if you open a collection the url looks like:

https://codecanyon.net/collections/4945814-about

And the numeric portion is the ID...but I sure could wish for more definitions or examples of what the parameters should look like. :-)

I looked around, but didn't find anything helpful on the web nor does there appear to be a forum hosted by Envato for discussing the API.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I did a same thing with all new themeforest wordpress theme with the API defined here: https://build.envato.com/api/

Comment: @Tristup - How? That is what I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code which I did to fetch data from envato API :

```
var themeforest_api="http://marketplace.envato.com/api/v2/new-files:themeforest,wordpress.json";
        $.getJSON( themeforest_api, {
            format: "json"
            }).done(function( data ) {
                var html='';
                $.each( data['new-files'], function( i, item ) {

                     html=html+'<li><a href="'+item.url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+item.thumbnail+'"></a></li>';
                     if ( i === 8 ) {
                      return false;
                    }
               });
            $("#all_items").append( html );           
        });
```

Hope it will help you for your one too.